# Out of Memory Downloading (Small) Image from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, out-of-memory

thanks for your interest.

I'm testing a small program of mine that's designed to the upload and retrieving of images from an SQL Server.

When I run the below code I get an 'Out of Memory' Error - though my PC has 8GB RAM and teh program's literally just a single form.

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DP FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID = 1", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim ImgStream As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Byte()))
PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ImgStream)
ImgStream.Dispose()
con.Close()
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Out of memory.

The debug is highlighting the `BackgroundImage =` line, if I change the `BackgroundImage` to just `Image`, the program works. But I sacrifice the layout option that way.

Why's this error occurring, and only when it's the `BackgroundImage`?

Comment: If you use `Image.FromStream(ImgStream, False, True)`, do you get a different exception? This code validates (third argument True) the image data.

Comment: it might also depend on how and what was saved to the DB - maybe it was improperly saved.  See if you can create an Image from the db and save it to disk so you can examine it.

Comment: The datatype on the SQL Server is Image. It stores the image in a hexadecimal format - from the look of it anyway.

Comment: @FrankPl The same Out of Error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on reader and then when it hits that breakpoint press F10 once, then check and make sure that you have something and it is indeed binary (image)...

```vb
Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("SELECT DP FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID = 1", con)
Dim reader as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim obj as Object, B() as Byte

If reader.HasRows Then
    While reader.Read()
        obj = reader.GetValue(0)
        Exit While
    End While
    If Not IsDBNull(obj) Then
        B = DirectCast(obj, Byte())
        Using ms as New IO.MemoryStream(B)
            PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the ExecuteScalar work?  Also, it's `HasRows` (plural) and you are missing a `reader.Read()` statement in your code.

Comment: Well you can, I used reader as there maybe more than one row returned from that query. Other than that you still can use scaler if "we" know that hes only returning one value. And thank you @LarsTech for pointing the read and hasrows out, doing it from a phone isn't the best solution I would say...

Comment: If you are expecting just one row, you can use `If reader.Read Then` and eliminate the `HasRows` check and the `While` loop.

Comment: Yes, Only expecting the 1 row. And the out of Memory error still occurs.

Comment: Are you sure it's binary data? If not it will throw an exception, did you set a breakpoint where I told you?